# Netbeans debugging in Java - Different execution

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

When I debug an application developed in Java using netbeans I get an error (the error comes from a c++ dll). If I execute the generated jar via command line everything works well.

Could you provide reasons to investigate why debugging the call to the library doesn't works and why executing the compiled jar it works?

I'm using a fresh installation of latest netbeans version.

Comment: Could you tell for the readers what the error is like?

Comment: The error comes from a library that tries to get the installed twain drivers. The obtaining of these drivers fails when I debug but works when I execute the compiled Jar.